# simple response to question

Tags: translation

> あなたは どうして 日本語を べんきょうしていますか

I would like to say so that I can read go book but I can only say I read go book.

> 碁のほんをよみます。

**EDIT**

Perhaps I can say:

> 日本語を べんきょうしています。碁のほんをよみますから。

Comment: your suggestion of 碁のほんをよみますから。 is actually fine, of course. "Because I read Go books." ... It doesn't really explain "why", because of course you could choose to read Go books in English, but as a simple explanation it is understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could say

"because I want to read Go books." ⮕ 碁のほんをよみたいから。

or

"because I want to be able to read Go books." ⮕ 碁のほんをよめるようになりたいから。